# why isn't the sfml image displayed?

Tags: c++, g++, sfml

i trying to set backgound in my sfml-application,
but the error appears
Code:

```
 Image hero_image;
hero_image.loadFromFile("image/main.png");
Texture hero_texture;
hero_texture.loadFromImage((hero_image));

Sprite hero_sprite;
hero_sprite.setTexture(hero_texture);
hero_sprite.setPosition(50,30); 
//main loop
window.draw(hero_sprite);
```

Error:

```
Failed to load image "image/main.png". Reason: Unable to open file
Failed to create texture, invalid size (0x0)
```

Comment: It seems because you executed your executable file with wrong working directory, or the image file is broken, or you don't have permission to read the file.

Comment: MikeCAT, soo...
how to fix directory problem?..

Comment: Use your file explorer to figure out where the image is located. Then read your documentation on your IDE to figure out what folder it sets to the working directory when debugging your application. A second method on this would be to simply create a file in your c++ code and use your file explorer to where it puts it. After you figure out what is the correct working directory adjust the path of the image file.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio ? If so, remember that the directory where your .exe is located is **not** your active directory when running the executable from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The first error `Failed to load image "image/main.png". Reason: Unable to open file` is caused because you have propably entered a bad file path.By path `"image/main.png"` your image should be in folder named `image` and your picture with name `main.png` should be inside this folder :). And of course your folder `image` should be inside your project location with`.cpp` and `.h` files.
The second error is caused because when  `Image hero_image;` isn't loaded properly by `Failed to load image "image/main.png". Reason: Unable to open file` error than your  `Image hero_image;` is empty.

Also using `sf::Image` instance which you load into `sf::Texture` is useless. Try doing just:

```
sf::Texture hero_texture;
hero_texture.loadFromFile("image/main.png");
sf::Sprite hero_sprite;
hero_sprite.setTexture(hero_texture);
```

Comment: Just a correction: the image file must be in the the same directory as the executable, not the .cpp/.h files

Comment: @Diego you are right, if you are running your game from your executable. But if you are running your game from your debugger or IDE then your resources must be where I mentioned